# why is my nine-patch is so small in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

I have these two **nine-patches :**

[image]

[image]

Here is my **XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/switch_bg"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:background="@drawable/switch_bg_off"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/switch_bg2"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/switch_bg_off" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/switch_handle"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/switch_handle"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/switch_v"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/switch_v" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

but in the graphic editor and in my app itself

the white box is cut in half and **seen improperly :**

[image]

**How can I fix this?**

Comment: Where you have created nine patch?

Comment: May your nine patch is not valid:

You can use http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html for create nine patch. Try this,

Comment: a designer made it with photoshop

Comment: okk you can post image on above url and save it... then try...

Comment: why do you think mine is not good?

Comment: :D dude, it happens sometimes... :) you can try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/switch_bg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/switch_bg_off"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/switch_bg2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/switch_bg_off" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/switch_handle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/switch_handle"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/switch_v"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/switch_v" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ok all fill_parent replace with wrap_content and tell me what hapnd